# Using wso2dss as AMQP consumer

Tags: wso2, rabbitmq, amqp, wso2-data-services-server

I am using `RabbitMq` as my message queue and I have to use `AMQP` protocol in my application. I am publishing messages to my queues in `RabbitMq` and consume the messages using `nodejs` client. As an enhancement I want to omit the `nodejs` consumer client and replace it with `WSO2 Data Service Server`, since currently the `nodejs` client calls the services hosted on `wso2-dss`, after fetching them from queue.

I searched a lot and I didn't find proper way to do this without using `wso2-esb`. I may be able to solve my problem with qpid client, but I really need help.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through  https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/RabbitMQ+AMQP+Transport and http://itsmaheeka.blogspot.com/2015/09/esb-490-enhanced-rabbitmq-support.html to get an idea about RabbitMq transport.ESB provides inbuilt RabbitMq transport But for DSS you may have to install required features.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, as I mentioned my setup, I want to remove the consumer layer and consume message just with DSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the DSS JMS transport[1] to achieve this, because RabbitMQ support JMS.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/DSS350/JMS+Transport